# Magento: Single Quotes in Translation Files Void Translation

Tags: magento, translation

I am trying to translate some strings from a Magento 1.5.x install and it works fine when there is a double quote, but I cannot properly escape single quotes.

```
"Hello, <strong>\'.Mage::getSingleton(\'customer/session\')->getCustomer()->getName().\'!</strong>","Hello, <strong>\'.Mage::getSingleton(\'customer/session\')->getCustomer()->getName().\'!</strong>","Ol&aacute;, <strong>\'.Mage::getSingleton(\'customer/session\')->getCustomer()->getName().\'!</strong>"

"<button class=""form-button"" onclick=""setLocation(\'%s\')"" type=""button""><span>Login or Register</span></button>","<button class=""form-button"" onclick=""setLocation(\'%s\')"" type=""button""><span>Login ou Cadastro</span></button>"
```

I've tried the original string as is, and escaped with a backslash. I've tried the translated string escaped with a backslash and double single quotes.

I tried searching the magento forum, but the only two people that posted about this problem got no replies.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Are those string above in phtml files? PHP files as strings?

Comment: the lines you've put as example looks like coming from the csv language files (for the structure "English string","Portuguese translation"), BUT you can't use php variable in there (aka `Mage::getSingleton()`. And the second one looks weird also, you don't translate html elements (button, span). As Alan said, give us more information about what is where and what you're trying to do

Comment: They are simply strings in a CSV file. I should have additionally used a simpler example ("Hello","Bonjour"). Anything that is echoed by magento and is inside quotes can be translated by simply being present in this file.

I know that translation including variables such as `"Shipment #%1$s | %3$s (%2$s)","Entrega #%1$s | %3$s (%2$s)"` DO work, though I have not found an example in the pre-translated files (the ones above are additional translations I have to use for my own theme) of variables like `Mage::getSingleton()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the way the strings were being output in PHP were not compatible with Magento's translation engine. The fix comprised changes in the PHP file, not in the syntax of the translation files. The PHP files now read:

```
echo $this->__('Hello') . ', <strong>'.Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName().'!</strong>';

echo ('<button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('customer/account/login') . '\')" type="button"><span>') . $this->__('Login or Register') . '</span></button>';
```

as opposed to having everything inside one `echo $this->__('String to be translated . phpcode. String to be translated . phpcode . etc . etc')`

Answer (score 10):

When you escape a single-quote with a backslash in the .phtml file, you need to remove the backslash from the translation string in the .csv file.

Example:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl())
```

Should be in .csv file:

```
"Click <a href=""%s"" onclick=""this.target='_blank'"">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.", "Click <a href=""%s"" onclick=""this.target='_blank'"">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation."
```

without the backslashes, otherwise the string won't get translated. As usual double-quotes in the .csv have to be escaped with another double-quotes.

Some .csv translation files in Magento 1.7.0.2 still have these backslashes before single-quotes, which is a minor bug that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Other option is that you can put error message in double quotes as

__("Please specify the product's option(s).");

and in translation file you make it by simple this

**Colum ONE**                            | **Colum Two**
Please specify the product's option(s).  | TRANSLATION OF that FILE

remove \ from Translation file and from code make it DOUBLE QUOTES in stead of single quote.

Answer (score 0):

You should never put html in a translated string. Magento uses vsprintf (http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) so it's easy to add a variable to a translation like this:

```
echo '<strong>'.$this->__('Hello %s!',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()).'</strong>';
```

In this way you can then translate easily in a csv: "Hello %s","Hola %s"